# How to include .sdf database file when packaging my application

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, clickonce

I was able to create an application in VB.net that talks to a SQL Server CE database.

Now i want to deploy this application using the publish feature with clickonce.

An issue im having tho is when I install the application on another computer it keeps looking for my sql server on my development pc.

Ive added the .sdf when i package my solution but its still an issue.

How do I change my connection string to connect to the .sdf file that I included in the package?

this is my current connection string which looks at the sql server:
 connectionString = " Data Source=CHRIS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ce_db;Integrated Security=True"

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

connectionString = "Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ce_db;Integrated Security=True"

or perhaps

```
connectionString = "Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\ce_db.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

this connection string would work if you had the database in the same directory as the executable using it.

essencially the data source is either the database server that you are connecting to, or the database file that you are connecting to.

If you are using a file then you have only one catalog. and if you are using a server then you will want to specify a specific catalog using the Initial catalog attribute of the connection string.

Comment: however I think this is going to require you to install sql express.

Comment: Hi Jason - im trying to limit the user from installing sql express, hence why i was using the CE edition with clickonce

Comment: They will still have to install the CE prereq. I created an application that merely opened the database from the hard drive. but i had to make an installer that downloaded the SQL CE from microsoft and installed it as well.

Comment: Yes true they will have to install the CE prereq... unfortunately i tried the 2 above strings and both didnt seem to work. Does the ce_db.sdf have to be placed into my project directory in a specific place? does it just need to be added to the project as an 'existing item?

Comment: well, as noted in the codeblock in my answer. you can use the file path that leads to the database as the data source rather then using the sql server and an accompanying initial catalog. that should give you the connection you need.

Comment: wherever it is placed, you will need the path to that file.